# App is ignoring my orientation when it changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a problem. I solved this problem here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870418/app-crashes-if-the-orientation-is-changing-in-uiwebview)

But now my app is ignoring my `orientation`. If I entered the login data and the new website is loaded but the `orientation` is not the same the app is ignoring the new `orientation`.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber alloc];
    NSLog(@"Inside!");
    NSLog(@"Orientation: %@", [self orientNr]);
    if( [[self orientNr] isEqualToNumber:@1] ) value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown];
    else if( [[self orientNr] isEqualToNumber:@2] ) value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    else if( [[self orientNr] isEqualToNumber:@3] ) value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
});
```

The app is going inside this block because I got the two logs at my console. The `orientation` is the correct one but it won't execute.

Why is the app ignoring my `orientation`? If I restart the app it's always portrait although it should be landscape.

## EDIT:

In my file plist.info I have configured Supported Interface Orientation
[image: info.plist]

## EDIT 2:

My code looks like
[image: dispatch_async]

[3]

[image: consoleLog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested you code in a new project and it works.
Please check on your info.plist if you configured "Supported Interface orientations" entry correctly:

[image]

---

There's a alternate way to force the rotation:

```
#import <objc/message.h>
```

Then when you want to force landscapeLeft orientation use this:

```
 ((void (*)(UIDevice *, SEL, int))objc_msgSend)([UIDevice currentDevice],@selector(setOrientation:),UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
```

Comment: Hi, I added an image of my info.plist. I configured it for iPad and iPhone

Comment: Ok then I assume that your "orientNr" method is not working as expected.

Comment: Replace [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"]; with  [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight] forKey:@"orientation"];

Comment: I added two images. Replacing ` [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];` has nothing changed. Orientation still ignored

Comment: I've tested the code in a new project and it works. I edited my answer to suggest you another way to force landscape orientation

Comment: Damn that's so annoying. It doesn't change anything. It's so frustrating. I don't know why it isn't work. But thanks for your help. The question is "Why is `dispatch_async()` ignoring my orientation although I need it?" Because my app is crashing without it. Schizophrenic xD